# graying out images using css

Tags: jquery, css

I have managed to gray out images in Firefox and IE9 using:

```
filter: url(../filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+  */
filter: gray; /* IE5+ */
```

but i cant seem to figure it out in chrome and safari. I have tried using

```
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome 18+ (currently Beta) */
```

but it doesn't work. any clue

Comment: try saturation(0%) or grayscale(100%)

Comment: you are right, doesn't work neither in safari 5.1

Comment: http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-grayscale/ this will do it!

Comment: The link you just posted is actually really nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found on the [following link](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-grayscale):

webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-grayscale

Answer (score 3):

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

http://www.css3.com/css-filter/

http://jsfiddle.net/S6ThD/1/

http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs

[image]
[image]

Comment: i think it happens in the browser... which is not really in your computer

Comment: My browser is on my computer. Where is yours? Phone? What version of which browser on which platform is this working for you samccone?

Comment: i think it is on the cloud or something

Comment: either that or on my FTL drive

Comment: OK Mr.Smart guy. Anyways, from what I can tell this is the correct syntax, I suppose it's just not well supported. Can only guess while you're being sarcastic, I wish you would just give it up and tell us where/how/what this is working on because I'm not seeing it. Requires Chrome 18? EDIT: Thank you for the graphic, where did you hipsters find a Chrome **19**? ;)

Comment: i think it was right next to my plaid shirt and gameboy color on top of my record player

Comment: but i had to throw my only masterball to catch it

Comment: Must have gotten lost amongst all the Tom Waits cassettes or under your scarf/converse shoes. Cool pic, is that your Noise band?

Comment: Its chrome canary, a beta version of chrome. http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs